# Find number of duplicate that occurs in array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I can't wrap my head around this. Need to find duplicates and I did. All now that is left is to print how many times a duplicate appears in the array. I just started with Java,so this needs to be hard coded for me to understand. Spend last two days trying to figure it out but with no luck.. Any help will be great! Talk is cheap,here is the code..

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class LoopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {12,23,-22,0,43,545,-4,-55,43,12,0,-999,-87};
        int positive_counter = 0;
        int negative_counter = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] > 0) {
                positive_counter++;
            } else if(array[i] < 0) {
                negative_counter++;
            }
        }

        int[] positive_array = new int[positive_counter];
        int[] negative_array = new int[negative_counter];

        positive_counter = 0;
        negative_counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] > 0) {
                positive_array[positive_counter++] = array[i];
            } else if(array[i] < 0) {
                negative_array[negative_counter++] = array[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Positive array: " + (Arrays.toString(positive_array)));
        System.out.println("Negative array: " + (Arrays.toString(negative_array)));

        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println("Array duplicates: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if(array[i] == array[j]) {                    
                    System.out.println(array[j]);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a map where key is a number and value is number of occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already sorting the array you can find the duplicates with just one loop (they will be next to each other right?). So you can do something like:

```
            Arrays.sort(array);
            System.out.println("Array duplicates: ");
            int lastValueCount=1; //How many times we met the current value (at least 1 - this time)
            for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){        
                    if(array[i] == array[i-1])                     
                        lastValueCount++;   //If it is the same as the previous increase the count  
                    else {
                       if(lastValueCount>1) //If it is duplicate print it
                           System.out.println(array[i-1]+" was found "+lastValueCount+" times");
                       lastValueCount=1; //reset the counter
                    }
            }
```

Result for your array is:

```
Array duplicates: 
0 was found 2 times
12 was found 2 times
43 was found 2 times
```

Also you can use some of the Java bells and whistles like inserting the values into Map or something like that but I guess you are looking from an algorithmic point of view so the above is the simple answer with just one loop

Comment: ((: it would not be as easier as like if the array wasn't sorted. But +1

Comment: Yes! This is excellent and things are looking so much clearer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just go through your solution, first you separate positive and negative numbers in two different arrays, then you never use them, so what's the purpose of this separation ?
I am giving you just an idea related to your problem, it's better to solve it by your self so that you can get hands on Java.

Solution: you can use Dictionary-key value pair. Go through your array, put element in dictionary as a key and value as zero, on every iteration check if that key already exist in Dictionary, just increment its value. In the end, all of the values are duplicates that occurs in your array.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is one of the many tests that my professor gave me to practice and understand arrays and loops. I wanted to finish it by myself but had no luck. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 1):

From the algorithmic point of view, Veselin Davidov's answer is good (the most efficient).

In a production code, you would rather write it like this :

```
Map<Integer, Long> result = 
    Arrays.stream(array)
          .boxed() //converts IntStream to Stream<Int>
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));
```

The result is this Map  :

```
System.out.println(result);
```

> {0=2, 545=1, -4=1, -22=1, -87=1, -999=1, -55=1, 23=1, 43=2, 12=2}

Comment: Good answer, but streams are probably an overkill keeping in mind that OP only just started learning java.

Comment: @TA I agree. This answer is more intended for future googlers because counting a number of occurrences is a common need.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be using Maps. Without changing code too much:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if(array[i] == array[j]) {                    
                System.out.println(array[j]);
                count++;
            }
        }
        map.put(array[i], count);
  }
```

Docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Edit: As a recommendation, after you are done with the example, you should analize your code and find what isn´t neccesary, what could be done better, etc.

Are all your auxiliary arrays neccesary?  Are all loops necessary?

Comment: You do not define your map variable anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating an array list for duplicate values:-

```
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println("Array duplicates: ");

ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if(j != i && array[i] == array[j] && !duplicates.contains(array[i])){
            duplicates.add(array[i]);
            System.Out.println(duplicates[duplicates.size()-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void findDuplicate(String s){

```
char[] charArray=s.toCharArray();
ArrayList<Character> duplicateList = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArray));

for(int i=0 ; i<=charArray.length-1; i++){
    if(duplicateList.contains(charArray[i]))
        continue;
    for(int j=0 ; j<=charArray.length-1; j++){
        if(i==j)
            continue;

        if(charArray[i] == charArray[j]){
            duplicateList.add(charArray[j]);
            System.out.println("Dupliate at "+i+" and "+j);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply a question with just code, please explain yours a little bit. In this case there are more answers so expose the Pros of yours.